# "No speakable text present" en ImageButton en AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio

Me aparece ImageButton: No speakable text present. Intenté ponerle texto o hint, pero no aparece la opción. En el código lo tengo así

```
                <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibBasurero"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:contentDescription="@string/basurero"
                android:contextClickable="false"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etPr1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:src="@drawable/basura" />
```

Edit: agregué la misma imagen 10 veces (con distinto ID) y ahora el error me aparece a partir de la 5ta solamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás segura de que `@string/basurero` contiene un string válido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema indica que no hay un texto para reproducir cuando el usuario usa el asistente, debe agregar una descripción del contenido para que el usuario pueda conocer información sobre la vista.

Además de agregar

```
android:hint="Este es el botón basurero"
```

agrega también su "Content description":

```
android:contentDescription="Este botón sirve como basurero"
```